# Rails: how to use scope with params and use route with default value of params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, default

I have such lines in routes.rb:

```
scope "/:subdomain/" do
  resource :order, :only => [:new, :create, :show, :update, :edit, :destroy] do
    get   :cancel,    :on => :member 
    put   :counter,   :on => :member 
  end
end
```

And for example, this is typical url: http://mydomain.com/some_subdomain/order/new . This url is mapped to action new of orders controller with params[:subdomain] = "some_subdomain". I want to use named route new_order_url(:subdomain => "some_subdomain").

But I want to map http://mydomain.com/order/new to orders controller, action new and params[:subdomain] = "default". And I want to use named route new_order_url for such url.

What is the best practices to do it?

Comment: One suggestion, use `resource :order, :except => [:index]` instead of `:only`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The answer is "use () and defaults"

```
scope "/(:subdomain)", :defaults => {:subdomain => "default"} do
  ...
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults

Comment: What's the purpose of putting `()` around the dynamic parameter? And where is the documentation for it?

Comment: @ArslanAli It makes the param optional: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#bound-parameters