# Get locale from scope in routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, locale

I have the following in my routes

```
scope "/(:locale)", locale: /en|fr/, constraints: LocaleConstraint do
  # I want to be able to detect the locale that was used in the URL
  get '/tool' , redirect_to(/a_certain_page)
end
```

Now depending on the locale that was in URL I want to redirect to different pages.

Basically I want the following:

```
get '/fr/tool', redirect_to(/tool_in_french)
get '/en/tool', redirect_to(/tool_in_english)
```

I'd expect something like:

```
scope "/(:locale)", locale: /en|fr/, constraints: LocaleConstraint do
  get '/tool' => locale == :fr ? redirect_to(/tool_in_french) : redirect_to(/tool_in_english)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better practice to find the language in the application_controller.rb using params.

```
private
def set_locale
  session['locale'] = params[:locale] || session['locale'] || I18n.default_locale
  I18n.locale = session['locale']
end
```

I'm not sure what kind of translation tool you're using but with I18n this works perfect. In the routes you should just add the :locale to the scope as a parameter. And this can be forced in the application_controller.rb. The scope was correct, without the defaults; [Rails: how to use scope with params and use route with default value of params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082579/rails-how-to-use-scope-with-params-and-use-route-with-default-value-of-params)

```
before_action :set_locale
```

If you're not using I18n you could still use this method to link to different view folders and route to the correct view file in every method of all the controllers, a lot of work.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: That what i am using normally ! But for this particular route, i have the same url for english and french, and the only difference is locale in the URL. So I have to get the locale in the routes.rb so i can redirect to different methods...

Comment: @RailsRails you could take a look at redirecting of non-resourcefull routes. I have to say it was a long scroll. I knew there was something. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection

Comment: Did that fixed your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not ! I had to redefine the routes outside of the :locale scope ( above basically ) as following: `get '/fr/tool', redirect_to(/tool_in_french)`and `get '/en/tool', redirect_to(/tool_in_english)`