# Rails 5.2: Is it possible to drop the first resource name from these nested routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have nested resources:

```
resources :volumes, only: :show do
  resources :chapters, only: :show do
    resources :characters, only: :index, :show
    end
  end
end
```

Which gives me the following routes:

```
volume_chapter_characters GET  /volumes/:volume_id/chapters/:chapter_id/characters(.:format)     characters#index
 volume_chapter_character GET  /volumes/:volume_id/chapters/:chapter_id/characters/:id(.:format) characters#show
           volume_chapter GET  /volumes/:volume_id/chapters/:id(.:format)                        chapters#show
                   volume GET  /volumes/:id(.:format)                                            volumes#show
```

I'm not sure if it's entirely RESTful but I want to know if there's a way of dropping the `volumes/` part of the URL so that I'd have something like:

```
volume_chapter_characters GET  /:volume_id/chapters/:chapter_id/characters(.:format)     characters#index
 volume_chapter_character GET  /:volume_id/chapters/:chapter_id/characters/:id(.:format) characters#show
           volume_chapter GET  /:volume_id/chapters/:id(.:format)                        chapters#show
                   volume GET  /:id(.:format)
```

Can it be done?

Comment: This can be done, but probably shouldn't be done. If you do this, you need to watch order of the routes very carefully. A small mistake and your `GET /users` instead of getting user list tries to load volume  with id "users".

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082579/rails-how-to-use-scope-with-params-and-use-route-with-default-value-of-params

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `path` option.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :volumes, only: :show, path: '' do
    resources :chapters, only: :show do
      resources :characters, only: [:index, :show]
    end
  end
end
```